# Navigation Bar covers my content when pushing to a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

When I push to a new `View Controller`, the `Navigation Bar`, from the embedded `Navigation Controller`, covers my `UITextField`. However, after [changing the orientation](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/3o72Flglqag1ScGyiI) from `Portrait` to `Landscape` then back to Portrait the UTTextField becomes visible and continues to be so regardless of further change of orientation.

I have a `UIScrollView` within the View Controller's View that I'm pushing too.

Within `Interface Builder` I have enabled `Under Top Bars` from `Extend Edges` and disabled `Adjust Scroll View Insets` from `Layout` because it didn't help.

I've been at a stand still with this; any help right now would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One trick to solve this problem is in viewDidLoad do

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
```

Now if you have a transparent header the view will no longer be seen threw it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It does solve the problem however, I would like to keep the View Controller's View to Extend Edges Under Top Bars so that I can have the Navigation Bar's translucency equal to true. Applying what you suggested yields the following [result](http://imgur.com/dcz4k1K). Looking at the [Debug View Hierarchy](http://imgur.com/dWCNxJY) I can see why the Navigation Bar appears a darkish-grayish color.

Answer (score 0):

How about add this in `viewDidLoad`

```
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
```